# Assertions in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-chromedriver

I am starting automation testing in selenium python .how we assert value java if java is available on the website or not [image].

I have added a pic of the website.

Website link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def testName(self):
        s =Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
        driver= webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
        driver.get("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm")

        
    
        actualString = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a").text
        actualString.assertTrue(actualString.contains("java"));



if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Your element `driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a")` refer to first element `a tag` in the page, if you try to print it will produce `Home`, not like you want as the picture attached. Please specific the issue, which your target.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm